# Android NPE while second calling interface

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface

I have some class `application class` extending `Application`. I use it as a controller  for filling the database and perfoming REST calls. There is an interface:

```
private OnDBfilled onFilledListener;
...
public void setOnFilledListener(OnDBfilled onFilledListener) {
    this.onFilledListener = onFilledListener;
}
public interface OnDBfilled {
    void onFilledCallback();
}
...
```

When I've got required  data  call it  to get known the `Fragment`, that data was successfully load from the internet and filled to database:

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
...//working with data
onFilledListener.onFilledCallback();
}
```

For the  first  time, when the call is done and database is filled  I can  see  the result in the log:

```
private Application controller;
private Application.OnDBfilled listener;
...
controller = new Application();
listener = new Application.OnDBfilled() {
        @Override
        public void onFilledCallback() {
            System.out.println("bd is filled. replacing fragments initiated editianal");
            replaceFragment();
        }
    };
 controller.setOnFilledListener(listener);
```

This works fine and I can see the  logging message. But  when I'm  trying to do in  the  another fragment, I've  got `Null Pointer Exception` in this line:

```
 onFilledListener.onFilledCallback();
```

Here's code of another  fragment,  but it's almost equal:

```
  private Application controller;
private Application.OnDBfilled filledDBListener;

...
//onCreateView
controller = new Application();
    filledDBListener = new Application.OnDBfilled() {
        @Override
        public void onFilledCallback() {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
           // fillEventListFromBD(UserData.getCity(getActivity()));
        }
    };
    controller.setOnFilledListener(filledDBListener);
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @RC what do you mean saying timing?

Comment: I misread, forget it

Comment: @RC your advices didn't help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnDBfilled  flid static

```
 private static OnDBfilled onFilledListener;
```

or

fragment & viewpager use:

```
 viewpager.setoffscreenpagelimit(9)
```

Comment: Did you even read the question?  Quoted from the question: 'I've got Null Pointer Exception in this line: `onFilledListener.onFilledCallback();`'